# Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: t0 = [t0]

Tags: haskell

I was trying to rewrite the Data.List.group using foldr, here is my code:

```
group' :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [[a]]
group' xs = foldr pack' [[head xs]] (tail xs)
     where
        pack' x acc = if x == (head $ head acc)
           then x:(head acc)
           else [x]:acc
```

now I get these errors:

```
Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: t0 = [t0]
In the expression: x
In the first argument of `(:)', namely `[x]'
In the expression: [x] : acc
```

And:

```
Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: t0 = [t0]
Expected type: [[t0]]
  Actual type: [[[t0]]]
In the second argument of `(:)', namely `acc'
In the expression: [x] : acc
In the expression:
  if x == (head $ head acc) then x : (head acc) else [x] : acc
```

Both refer to the last line.

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something but I don't really catch what since the type of pack' should be:

```
pack` a -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
```

Comment: The problem had nothing to do with parentheses at all! In fact, even in your original code, you had more than necessary. `(x : head acc) : tail acc` would have been sufficient, and normally it's a good idea to use only as many parens as necessary. – _Really_, the problem was apparently that you somehow commented out the `: tail acc`, accidentally. (I wonder how!)

Comment: Random style comment: avoid partial functions such as `head,tail`, and use pattern matching. This helps in remembering to cover all the cases (e.g. `xs=[]`).

Comment: I'k prety new to haskell and parenthesis are assuring I will try slim them down as much as possible now :)

Comment: I rolled back your question's edits, so it applies to the original problem (which Peter Hall has correctly adressed).

Comment: @leftaroundabout try compiling the code without parenthesis and the problem still remains :/

Comment: No it doesn't, you've probably again missed the `: tail acc`.

Comment: probably I was only messing the code up btw

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
then x:(head acc)
```

And this one

```
else [x]:acc
```

Should have the same type. But each are consing different types to the head of a list. This is what it means when it says "cannot construct the infinite type: t0 = [t0]". If `a` = `[a]` then it must be an infinite-dimensional list.

Comment: ... and the solution (as the OP had already noticed himself) is to make `x:(head acc)` merely the head of a nested-list, namely `(x : head acc) : tail acc`.

Answer (score 1):

This is really a comment, and it was already brought forth by chi, but perhaps it help to actually show this: the "correct" way to do such a function is without `head` and `tail`, which can be replaced with pattern matching. Also, `if` is typically nicer rewritten as guards.

```
group' :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [[a]]
group' (x0:xi) = foldr pack' [[x0]] xi
     where
        pack' xn acc@((x:xs):xss)
              | xn == x    = (xn : x : xs) : xss
              | otherwise  = [x]:acc
```

With warnings enabled, the compiler will (as it should!) now shout at you that this isn't defined for empty lists. So you add

```
group' [] = []
```

Within `pack'`, we're actually sure the empty case can't happen.

Comment: Actually is more readable but harder to grasp at first glance, it just does not comes up to an haskell novice I guess. THe `group' [] = []` should not be `group' [] = [[]]`

Comment: Right. But better readability is not the main benefit of this style, it's _safety_. Partial functions like `head` may break your program in unexpected and hard-to-trace ways.

Comment: Now I have a problem I did use your code for doing a slight variation of the thing, namely the (number 10) [(number,item)] in Haskell-99  problems and finished with the head of the starting list as the last element of the computed one. at the point it get mixed up with the last element of the starting list. Here using last and init seems unavoiable.

Comment: p.s. It does so also with group'

Comment: That's subject for another question.